# Personhood of the Holy Spirit

Tags: biblical-basis, trinity, pneumatology

All the arguments I have read for a unique personhood of the Holy Spirit separate from the Father or Son are comprised of passages that show the Spirit’s emotions or independent will.

**(Example references taken from CARM.org)**

- Is 63:10; Eph 4:30 - Grieves
- Rom 15:30 - Loves
- Rom 8:27 - Has a mind
- 2 Sam 23:2; Acts 8:29, 10:19, 11:12, 13:2, 21:11, 28:25-26; 1 Tim
  4:1; Heb 3:7-8; Rev 2:7, 14:13, 22:17 - Speaks
- 1 Cor 2:11 - Knows
- Acts 15:28 - Has preference
- Acts 5:3 - Can be lied to
- Acts 5:9 - Can be tested
- Acts 5:32 - Is a witness
- Acts 7:51 - Can be resisted

However there are passages showing a broad range of emotion and independent will of human spirits as well. In order to remain logically consistent, this would mean that one would have to believe our own spirits are unique persons separate from ourselves. However few would take this position.

- Matt 26:11/Mar 14:38 - The disciple’s spirits have a will
- Luk 1:47 - Mary’s spirit rejoices
- Acts 17:16 - Paul’s spirit is provoked
- Acts 18:25 - Apollos is fervent in spirit
- Rom 1:9 - Paul’s spirit serves God
- Rom 8:16 - Singular spirit of multiple believers testifies alongside the Holy Spirit
- Rom 12:11 - Is fervent
- 1 Cor 2:11 - Can know things. Also compared to how the Spirit of God knows the thoughts of God
- 1 Cor 14:2 - Speaks
- 1 Cor 14:14 - Prays
- 1 Cor 14:15 - Prays and sings
- 1 Cor 14:16 - Blesses by giving thanks
- 1 Cor 16:18; 2 Cor 7:13 - Is refreshed
- 2 Cor 2:13 - Needs rest

With that in mind, what are the grounds to defend the unique personhood of the Holy Spirit rather than it merely being the Spirit of the Father or the Son?

Comment: You also have a third option. Which is that it is both. It is the spirit of the father and son - but when it is "sent" to earth for a specific purpose it becomes independent of them and so obtains person hood. Best analogy I can think of to explain this is from horticulture and vegetative propagation by cuttings. You have a tree. You have a branch which is part of the tree. You cut off the branch and replant it - it becomes it's own independent tree which is identical to its parent. It is only in the "cutting" process the branch becomes an independent tree and same would be true for spirit.